# Sort arraylist from the value of another arraylist in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Current scenario,

I have 3 arraylist

```
name = [a,b,c,a]
age = [2,3,5,6]
score = [3,4,4,1]
```

As an outcome I want

```
name = [b,c,a,a]
age = [3,5,2,6]
score = [4,4,3,1]
```

I figured that using a map would be useful but I got confused after doing `score.map{v -> index}` :|

Comment: Convert your three separate lists into a single list of some new object (that has `name`, `age`, and `score` properties) and then sort that list. You can then convert that sorted list of objects back to three separate lists if you want.

Comment: Wouldn't it increase required space and time? @BenP.

Comment: Theoretically, but it would be negligible unless these lists have hundreds of thousands of items in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your values all belong to each other like in a table, for example:

```
        | name | age | score
------------------------------
index 0 |  a   |  2  |   3
index 1 |  b   |  3  |   4
index 2 |  c   |  5  |   4
index 3 |  a   |  6  |   1
```

and you want to sort it by the `score` column.

There are multiple approaches to solve this issue, so I will show my favorite one below.

## Using a data class

#### Declare the data class

For this purpose, it would be good to declare a simple data class that acts as a wrapper around the three variables. (You could also use the predefined Kotlin class `Triple`)

```kotlin
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int, val score: Int)
```

... creates a simple data class that fits your needs. Each instance of the data class
represents the values of all three array lists at one index (one row on the table above).

#### Convert the lists

To convert your three lists to an instance of the `User` class, you can use the Kotlin extension function `mapIndexed` which transforms a list into a list of another type while providing us with the elements and its index, which we need to access the proper values in the other lists.

```kotlin
val users = name.mapIndexed { index, value -> User(value, age[index], score[index]) }
```

Now we have a list of users that looks like this:

```
[User(name=a, age=2, score=3), User(name=b, age=3, score=4), User(name=c, age=5, score=4), User(name=a, age=6, score=1)]
```

#### Sort the list

And we can now simply append the `sortedByDescending` function to order sort it in descending order:

```kotlin
val usersSorted = name.mapIndexed { index, value -> User(value, age[index], score[index]) }.sortedByDescending { it.score }
```

It is always best practice to use classes if you want to store more than two values of an object, especially in this case.

#### Go back to the original lists

If you (somehow) still need the original lists, you can get them back by using the `map` function. But please note that this form of data isn't very handy.

```kotlin
val name = users.map { it.name }
val age = users.map { it.age }
val score = users.map { it.score }
```